# How can i paging in ElasticSearch over 10000 documents?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, paging

ElasticSearch support search paging like this.

```
GET /_search
{
 "from": 5,
 "size": 20,
 "query": {
   "match": {
     "user.id": "kid"
   }
 }
}
```

but, `from`+`size` is limit 10000. so i can't use `from` over 10000.

I need more than 10M!

ES document say to use search_after api. (my es version is 7.17)
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/paginate-search-results.html#search-after

I think, i can get all documents by this api.
however, can i get just 20000~20050 documents by this?

I can't know what is `sort value` of 20000 document without read 0~20000.
so i can't get exactly 20000~20050!

there are some way to get it?
please help me!

Comment: Sounds like [using SQL pagination would be more suitable for your specific task](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/sql-pagination.html)

Comment: @Filburt sorry, i can't understand why that link is solution of my question. can i get 20000~20050 by that?

Answer (score 0):

I think Elasticsearh is mainly used for searching data and not for persisting the data. Based on your question, you want to get all the users' data with pagination to 20M records.

I think Elasticsearch search has a limit to 10000 for the pagination from the context that any real person that is doing a search for any data in elasticsearch engine then he/she should be able to get the data within first 10000 records only as if he/she is not able to get the records within 10000 data then search query or what the user wants actually is not clear. This is the base why elasticsearch is specifically used for searching only.

Based on the question you have I can say you should use any persistent system to store to data and read from the same to get all the data that is needed by your system.